# throwing an exception in cakephp 2.0 always causes a 500 internal error

Tags: cakephp, exception, http-status-code-404

I have the following bit of code in my AppController, which I'm using to intercept a 404 and run some code beforehand. Right now I've trimmed it all back to basics whilst debugging.

```
public function appError($error) {
  throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

The exception name is irrelevent at this point, my problem is its causing a 500 error no matter what exception I throw.

All I want to do is throw a 404 and display my 404 page, which works fine if I enter a non-existent URL into my app.

Is there something that I'm missing at is causing this 500? I can't get any meaningful error messages, as its just showing the exception error 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception inside appError() itself will just cause a loop and cake will bail out with a 500 error

Answer (score 2):

Ok fixed, heres what I did:

Since ADmad kindly pointed out that I was creating an infinite loop, I did the following:

```
/**********************************
/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php
***********************************/

App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function error400($error) {
        /***********************
        INSERT MY OWN MAGIC HERE
        ***********************/
        $message = $error->getMessage();
        if (Configure::read('debug') == 0 && $error instanceof CakeException) {
            $message = __d('cake', 'Not Found');
        }
        $url = $this->controller->request->here();
        $this->controller->response->statusCode($error->getCode());
        $this->controller->set(array(
            'name' => $message,
            'url' => h($url),
            'error' => $error,
            '_serialize' => array('name', 'url')
        ));
        $this->_outputMessage('error400');
    }
}
```

And I also found I had to add this into /Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
        'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
        'renderer' => 'AppExceptionRenderer',
        'log' => true
));
```

If you want to include components, to quote ADmad:

"The exception renderer has the reference to controller which is an instance of CakeErrorController. Use **$this->controller->Components->load()** to load your component."

Comment: Big thanks to ADmad, renan_saddam & jose_zap for all their help on  the #cakephp IRC.

Comment: Since his anwser was correct and helped you, it would be nice to mark it as right or at least +1 as useful.